# Wrong day in weather notification

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, weather

Every morning I get a notification about weather at my location. However, at some point it started showing one day in advance - or a day off. For example, the following screenshot was taken on Tuesday, but it tells me the weather for Wednesday. What has happened and how can I fix it?

My phone's OS is Android 6.0

[image]

Comment: Which device? Is it a third party app that gives this information? Please link that app from Play store.

Comment: Check if the time zone is set to *automatic* in your settings and also *date and time* is provided by network , again in your settings

Comment: @beeshyams I believe that it's google now, and all those settings are as you say.

Comment: Somehow the screenshot got lost (maybe it didn't survive the migration), I've added it back.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments above suggest, you may have to check your time zone in Settings. On stock Android, it can be accessed under **System > Date & time**. The best thing to do is to select "Automatic time zone" if you have a cellular network connection; this will automatically set your time zone for you. If you can't, you should set in manually under the **Select time zone** option. If your time zone is correct, then it could be the app that is displaying the weather instead; uninstall it and reinstall it, and see if it is fixed.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem